# ¿Cómo cambiar el valor de un atributo en todas las Personas? (Firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase

Quiero hacer lo siguiente, esta es mi `database` en *Firebase*

```
DatabaseReference referenciaPersonasFirebase = database.getReference("Personas");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es un método que dentro de `Personas` busque en cada apartado el *atributo* `esNuevo` y sustituya el *valor* por `false` de todos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que se me ocurre es que iteres sobre todas las referencias que tiene persona y que a cada elemento le cambies el flag.

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
final DatabaseReference referenciaPersonasFirebase = database.getReference("Personas");

referenciaPersonasFirebase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Iterable<DataSnapshot> personas = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
        for(DataSnapshot persona: personas){
            DatabaseReference referenciaPersonaFirebase = database.getReference("Personas/"+persona.getKey());
            referenciaPersonaFirebase.child("esNuevo").setValue(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```